# How is the equivalence relation for the cosets of a Polynomial Quotient Ring defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, set-theory, equivalence-relations, polynomial-rings

When you partition $Z$ into cosets of Equivalence Classes using say $5Z$, then each element of the group $Z/5Z$ is an equivalence class which is defined by the relation $p \equiv q \bmod 5$ where $p$ & $q$ are from that equivalence class.

If I try something similar with a Polynomial Ring, say $Z[x]$.

For e.g. I construct $Z[x]/\langle x \rangle$ - now this again has elements which are actually an equivalence class of polynomials. How exactly do I write down the equivalence relation for each element in each coset of $Z[x]/\langle x \rangle$ the way we write $p \equiv q \bmod 5$ for $Z/5Z$?

If I want to generate all elements of the equivalence class $[\bar 2]$, the $p \equiv q \bmod 5$ relation tells me how to do it. For e.g. I can do that as {2, 2+5, 2+2*5, 2+ 3*5, 2+4*5 ....]. How would I generate all the elements of one equivalence  class in $Z[x]/\langle x \rangle$ or $Z[x]/\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$?

Comment: You mean other than $P(X)\equiv Q(X) \mod X$?

Comment: @Bcpicao - So if it's $Z[x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$ then it would be $P(X) \equiv Q(X) \bmod (x^2+1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the elements of the quotient ring $R/I$ are the equivalence classes of the following equivalence relation $\sim$ on $R$:
$$ \forall a,b\in R\,\ \ \ \ \ \ a\sim b\iff a-b\in I.$$
For $a\sim b$ we also write $a\equiv b\ \ \text{mod}\ I$.

For $R/I=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ we get the familiar relation
\begin{align*}
a\sim b &\iff a-b\in 5\mathbb{Z}\iff a-b=5k\  \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z} \\ 
&\iff 5\mid a-b \iff a\equiv b\mod 5.
\end{align*}
For $R/I=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x\rangle$ we get
\begin{align*}f\sim g &\iff f-g\in \langle x\rangle \\
&\iff f-g=x\cdot h\ \ \text{ for some } h\in\mathbb{Z}[X] \\ 
&\iff x\mid f-g \ \ \text{ in }\,\mathbb{Z}[x].
\end{align*}
So the analogue notation $``f\equiv g\mod \langle x\rangle"$  for $f\sim g$ makes sense.

Comment: If I want to generate all elements of the equivalence class $[\bar 2]$, I can do that as {2, 2+5, 2+2*5, 2+ 3*5, 2+4*5 ....]. How would I generate all the elements of any equivalence  class in $Z[x]/\langle x \rangle$ or $Z[x]/\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$?

Comment: @user93353 As you mentioned, in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ we have 
$$ [2]=\{2+5k\ \mid\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x\rangle$ we have
$$ [f(x)]=\{f(x)+x\cdot g(x)\ \mid\  g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\},$$
and in  $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ we have
$$ [f(x)]=\{f(x)+(x^2+1)\cdot g(x)\ \mid\ g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}.$$

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z} /5\mathbb{Z}$ there are $5$ equivalence classes. How many are there in $\mathbb{Z} /(x^3+2)$? Thanks.